# Rspec/Capybara: Devise user 'dissapears' after logging in

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, selenium-webdriver, devise, capybara

I'm having a bizarre problem where I create an `admin` user for an Rspec/Capybara test and the user is mysteriously deleted after logging in. When I run my test, the user is created and successfully logged in. However when Capybara visits the `admin_categories_path`, the test fails. Rails raises an exception because `current_user` is not defined. When I insert a `binding.pry`, I can see that the user exists up until they are logged in, at which point the user disappears from the test database, causing `current_user` to be undefined, and thereby triggering an exception. I'm at a loss as to how/why this is happening.

UPDATE: I've gotten past the problem of the user being deleted. Now when Capybara sees the `admin_categories_path` page, `category` isn't displayed. Inserting a `binding.pry` reveals that category is present in the database.

When I launch the app and log in manually, I have no problems accessing `admin_categories_path`.

Here is my spec file:

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'admin edits category', %Q{
  As an admin, I want to edit a category or subcategory, so that it better
  represents the content under it.
  Acceptance Criteria:
  * [X] - I can edit the name of a category inline.
  * [X] - I can edit the name of a subcategory inline.
  } do

  let(:admin) do
    FactoryGirl.create(:user, admin: true)
  end

  let(:category) do
    FactoryGirl.create(:category)
  end

  scenario 'admin edits category title', js: true, focus: true do
    login_as(admin)
    visit admin_categories_path

    bip_area category, :name, 'Test Category'
    expect(page).to have_content 'Test Category'
  end
end
```

Here is my helper file `authentication.rd`:

```
module Helpers
  module Authentication
    def log_in_as(user)
      visit new_user_session_path

      within "#new_user" do
        fill_in 'user[email]', with: user.email
        fill_in 'user[password]', with: user.password
        click_on "Log in"
      end
    end
  end

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.include Authentication, :type => :feature
  end
end
```

Here is my `user` factory:

```
require 'factory_girl'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) {|n| "lafiel.abriel#{n}@abhnation.com" }
    username
    password 'password'
    password_confirmation 'password'
  end

  factory :category do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Category ##{n}" }
    parent_id nil
    display_index 1
    user
  end

  sequence :username do |n|
    "Lafiel_Abriel_#{n}"
  end
end
```

And here is my `application_controller.rd` where the exception is triggered:

```
module Admin
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
    before_action :reject_unless_admin
    layout 'admin/layouts/application'

    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    helper :avatar, :devise, :admin

    protected

    def reject_unless_admin
      unless current_user && current_user.admin?
        raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('404: Not Found')
      end
    end

    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << [
        :avatar,
        :remote_avatar_url,
        :email,
        :username,
        :first_name,
        :last_name,
        :age,
        :website,
        :password,
        :password_confirmation,
        :current_password
      ]
    end
  end
end
```

Any help/insight is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem with the current_user not being present after successful login. The weirdest thing is that this happens in some tests only: especially when a bunch worked correctly, then all of a sudden, the last test fails with this behaviour. Anyway, it would be great if you could share if and how you solved your problem! Thanks.

Comment: Check my answer below. Hope that helps a little bit!

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, this problem had something to do with the test database schema being out of sync with the development database. Try running `rake db:test:prepare` to ensure your test schema matches your development schema.

In my specific case, I had a two problems to overcome.

The first problem occurred when I created a `category` and an `admin` in a `let` block. Those needed to be placed in a `before` block so that they were created before the test executed. When I placed those variables in `let` blocks, they were not being created until the first time they were called in the test. So when I logged in as an admin, the `admin` variable was being passed to my `login_as` helper method before it was saved to the database. The same is true for the `category` variable.

This code doesn't work for me:

```
let(:admin) do
    FactoryGirl.create(:user, admin: true)
end

let(:category) do
    FactoryGirl.create(:category)
end

scenario 'admin edits category title', js: true, focus: true do
    login_as(admin)
    visit admin_categories_path

    bip_area category, :name, 'Test Category'
    expect(page).to have_content 'Test Category'
end
```

This is solution I used to overcome the first problem:

```
before(:each) do
    @admin = FactoryGirl.create(:user, admin: true)
    @category = FactoryGirl.create(:category, user: @admin)
end

scenario 'admin edits category title', js: true do
    skip "Doesn't work yet."
    login_as(@admin)
    visit admin_categories_path

    wait_for_ajax
    bip_text @category, :name, 'Test Category'
    expect(page).to have_content 'Test Category'
end
```

The second problem is that when my test hits the `admin/categories_controller.rb`, `Category.all` returns an empty array, even though `@category.save!` and `@category.valid?` return true when I test my `before` block. I was never able to find a solution to the problem and ended up putting the test on ice.

I think part of the problem is that the documentation for the Best-in-Place gem is not very good. I used it at the time because it was an easy solution to my problem. Going forward though, I would use something like angular for this use-case. The documentation is much better and it's not a black box like a lot of gems are.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what bip_area does, but since your test says that it's editing a category I assume you are expecting the category to be present on the page when you visit admin_categories_path.  When you visit that path however category has not yet been created since you are using 'let' which is lazily evaluated (created at time of first use of the variable), so it would not be shown on the screen for you to edit.  Using binding.pry and then looking at that variable would actually create it, so it might be confusing you into thinking it was there.  You can use 'let!' instead which will force the variable to be created before each test instead of lazily evaluating it.

Comment: Is `let!` any different than `before`? They seem the same to me. I know now that `let` isn't evaluated until it's called (didn't know this at the time...).

Comment: let! allows you to define local variables as opposed to instance variables (no @ before the name)